# zookeeper prevents WebLogic froms shutting down completely

Tags: java, linux, jvm, weblogic, apache-zookeeper

So I have a java application that i recently included zookeeper in. This app is deployed on a WebLogic 11g server. since using zookeeper, when i run stopWebLogic.sh to shutdown my server, the WebLogic server goes into the SHUTDOWN mode, but WLS JVM process keeps running.
I am almost sure zookeeper is somehow preventing JVM from going down.

So my quesitons is, how can force ZooKeeper to get killed 100% when i try to shutdown WebLogic.

In stopWebLogic.sh as the first line i put the following line :

echo kill | nc 127.0.0.1 2181

however it didn't work and JVM still was running after WLS shutdown.

Comment: How do you know that the ZooKeeper is culprit? What is your ZooKeeper topology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to change the following line of stopWebLogic.sh script from

```
echo "shutdown('${SERVER_NAME}','Server', ignoreSessions='true')" >>"shutdown.py"
```

to

```
echo "shutdown('${SERVER_NAME}','Server', force='true', ignoreSessions='true')" >>"shutdown.py"
```

after about 10 second after WLS is in SHUTDOWN Mode, the JVM will go away now.

Answer (score 0):

ZooKeeper had a related bug. Could this be it:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-846

Also, consider, if possible looking into Netflix Curator for ZooKeeper:
https://github.com/netflix/curator